# Facebook Android SDK: AccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync() not extending expiration

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token

My Android app is using the Android Facebook SDK's `LoginManager` and `AccessToken` classes. We use `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions()` to initially link a Facebook account to our service. This method works fine and has no issues.

The issue we are having is when we're trying to refresh a Facebook access token upon our app starting (in the background you could say). For this, we use `AccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync()`, which from [Facebook's docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessToken/) states that it extends an access token's expiration. I'll note that the callback provided in this case does fire the `OnTokenRefreshed()` method, so it at least appears to be functioning. However, upon checking (from our backend services) we can see that the expiration date for that access token has not been extended since `refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync` was called.

Here's a snippet:

```
if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null)
{
    return;
}

AccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync(new AccessToken.AccessTokenRefreshCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void OnTokenRefreshed(AccessToken accessToken)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnTokenRefreshed >> " + accessToken);
    }

    @Override
    public void OnTokenRefreshFailed(FacebookException exception)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "OnTokenRefreshFailed >> " + exception.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + exception.getMessage(), exception);
    }
});
```

However, again I'll mention that we notice on the backend that the expiration date is still set to ~60 days from when it was initially linked using `FacebookManager.getInstance().loginWithReadPermissions()`.

Any ideas why the expiration date isn't changing? Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The caveat is in the fine print in the doc:

> extends the expiration date, *if extension is possible*

Extending access tokens by virtue of just wishing to extend expiration is no longer offered. See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing The 'refresh' function really now just refreshes permissions. Of course, there is this sort of puzzling note

> These tokens will be refreshed once per day, for up to 90 days, when
>   the person using your app makes a request to Facebook's servers.

I take it to mean that if the app performs one of the graph API requests then the expiration may be extended still only to a maximum of 90 days.